# Adding a single backslash (\) to a string in R

Tags: r, knitr

I am working on `knitr` right now, One of the string that I was trying to print has the `%` symbol. I read up on the TeX manual that to a print the `%` symbol. TeX should have the string as `\%` to display the code.

Using the command `gsub` I tried to do the following:

```
try = "0% success"
try2 = gsub("%","\%",try,fixed = TRUE)
```

`gsub` throws an invalid escape character error

If I do this:

```
try = "0% success"
try2 = gsub("%","\\\\%",try,fixed = TRUE)
```

`knitr` will still not be able to print the string

Please suggest me with a way that I can solve my problem

--------EDIT------------------

I want the string in try to displayed as it is in my output PDF
I am using this in knitr as \textit{\Sexpr{try}}
When the tex file gets created, it believes that the text after percentage is a comment.
I am creating an rnw file first and then creating the tex file, after which using texi2pdf to get the pdf file

----EDIT 2 -------------

I am not very good with either knitr or LaTeX

Comment: Could you please elaborate your workflow? Are we to understand that these commands are to be included in a knitr chunk? What is the desired output in LaTeX?

Comment: I want the string to be displayed as it is, my output pdf that I am generating should have the string "0% success" printed the way it is.
But when knitr encounters the % it believes the string to be a comment, I am using this in knitr as \textit{\Sexpr{try}}

Comment: You still haven't clarified. There are many paths from Knitr to LaTeX. Is it via Rmd? Or Rnw? Are you having problems echoing R commands in the PDF? Or are you trying to create LaTeX code with an R function? When I plug your code in knitr, I have no issues displaying % in PDF. I knit an MD file, and the resulting .tex gives \begin{verbatim}
try = "0% success"
try
\end{verbatim}

\begin{verbatim}
[1] "0% success"
\end{verbatim}

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand initially what you asked for..
I am creating an rnw file, then creating the tex. The texi2pdf operation is not able to print it.

Comment: So basically you want to create a variable in R (containing "0% success") and then render it in the string \textit{\Sexpr{try}}, where `try` is that variable in R?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

why are you jumping fomr one "\" to 4 "\"?

```
> try2 = gsub("%","\\%",try,fixed = TRUE)
> try2
[1] "0\\% success"
```

This should be read as `"\\"`, which (as far as i know) the regular expression will understand as an "\".

I hope i understood you right- and this is a possible sulution for you!

Comment: No, texi2pdf operation still thinks of the string after the % operation as a comment and gives me an error in that process because of that.

Comment: oh, sorry! Now i can see your problem- but i can´t reproduce it;

Comment: You were right, so If I put two // and output from R. It does come out perfectly, sorry my bad

Answer (score 5):

You need two backslashes to escape:

```
<<>>=
try = "0\\% success"
@

Some text in LaTex \Sexpr{try}.
```

After knitting the document one obtains the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlstd{try} \hlkwb{=} \hlstr{"0\textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}% success"}
\end{alltt}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}

Some text 0\% success

\end{document}
```

This, of course, assuming `echo=TRUE`.

Comment: This still causes the problem? You can see its being knitd to `\textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}%` instead of the desired `\%`

Comment: I can see that, but that is contained within the knitrout environment. I have used the PDF compiler which is provided in R studio internally, as well as TeX Studio to confirm the generalizability. Both conversions gave me the required PDF. For your convenience I've included all three files in a zip http://goo.gl/CCll9W

Comment: Ah I'm not familiar with the knitrout environment. I didn't see that it had compiled the `Some text 0\% success` as well!

Answer (score 0):

Other way to solve this issue is to use raw strings:

```
try = "0% success"
try2 = gsub(r"(%)", r"(\%)", try, fixed = TRUE)
try2
#[1] "0\\% success"
```